# Create tag for telegram-messenger

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I asked a question about telegram-messenger [Telegram Messenger on a Google Voice number](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79384/telegram-messenger-on-a-google-voice-number)

There is no tag for it, Would it be possible to create a new tag for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added [telegram](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telegram) to the question